# Buck Converter Voltage Fluctuation

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck-boost

Why the Voltage in output of Buck Converter fluctuates when there is a step change in load?

Comment: Why does any real voltage source fluctuate when suddenly connected to a load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because the control loop can't follow fast enough, however this doesn't happen only in buck converters, it happens in all power supplies.

A solution to that is to put a big enough decoupling capacitor at the output, that can catch that transient without causing a significant drop, giving time to the control loop to respond. Also, if you have a long transmission line from the supply to the load, you may need to add a decoupling capacitor close to the load too, as the line inductance will also generate a voltage drop on the load.

Also, if the control loop of the supply is not properly compensated, you can get ringing at the output.

Comment: But for the reduction of ripples, we have already placed a capacitor in parallel. Can't an extra capacitor affect the design parameters?

Comment: Yes it can. More capacitance will provide the energy while the control loop responds to the increased current draw. Also capacitors with smaller ESR and ESL can provide more current and faster. But too much capacitance can make it unstable. So at some point you can't add more capacitance, so you need to find a different buck converter that can handle the load and changes of the load too.